# Backing up VM data to host drive on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have created a VM for Virtual PC in Windows 7. I am writing a batch file to backup data in the VM to a host USB drive. I have shared the host drives. I have a USB drive that I want backup to target but how do refer to the USB drive in the batch file?

I cannot seem to map a drive to it; it is called "H on Malcolm-Desktop" in Windows Explorer.

This is what I have tried:

```
XCOPY C:\Inetpub\wwwroot "\\\H on Malcolm-Desktop\HALII_VHD_Backup\DataBackup\Inetpub\wwwroot" /S /E /Y /D
```

How do I write this command?

Answer (score 1):

As it has been over a year, I hope you have an answer, but just seen this question bumped, so I will try to help if you haven't.

Try double clicking on the item in my computer, this should then in the address bar have the full path... e.g. `\\computer_nam\share`, copy this and click on `Tools` > `Map Network Drive`, (you may need to press <kbd>alt</kbd> once in order to bring the menu bar up.

Next paste the address in to the path to share, and choose a drive.

You should now be able to run `xcopy` using a standard drive letter, which should be easier.

Comment: Comment by @Brett: Hi Malcolm - Did you ever get an answer to your question? I am trying to work out exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The USB drive should have a letter, what you're referring to is just the drive label. The letter should be beside the drive in **My Computer**.

Comment: No it doesn't have one. Thats all it says H on Malcolm-Desktop